# How to reliably check if your bitcoin onion node is reachable as advertised?

Tags: network, nodes, tor, p2p, bitnodes

If `getpeerinfo` returns a good number of outbound onion peers but none show up as `inbound:true`, how do you check if your node is properly reachable as advertised?

Several guides and forum answers recommend checking with Bitnodes(dot)io but this service is unable to reach the majority of my undeniably reachable outbound onion peers. My node and others don't show up as reachable on Bitnodes.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is
bitcoin-cli -netinfo

```
Bitcoin Core v22.0.0 - 70016/Satoshi:22.0.0/

        ipv4    ipv6   onion   total   block
in         0       0       1       1
out        9       1       0      10       2
total      9       1       1      11
```

My understanding is that for a node to be 'reachable' it must accept inbound connections in addition to outbound ones.
The output above suggest the node is 'reachable' over tor, with one inbound connection.

Running bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo shows connection info for the 11 connected nodes.

10 of which have

```
"connection_type": "outbound-full-relay"
```

and 1 of which has

```
"connection_type": "inbound"
```

As far as I can tell https://bitnodes.io/ is checking for clear web connected nodes and hence the above node will appear as unreachable using the bitnodes scan.

Comment: Well, -netinfo tells you if someone is currently connected to you, but even if no one is you might still be reachable.
Besides the bitnodes service, another option is to ask a friend to connect to you or use a second computer of yourself that is not on the same network, e.g. using mobile internet (no need to have synced the entire blockchain for that!).